# Micro Layers: Do not add functionality on top but simplify overall Dependencies

Tags: refactoring, clean-architecture, design-principles

I was going through design principles but could not understand this principle(avoid Micro layers), what would the significance be. I tried to google it but could not find any examples or explanation for this design principle. Could it possible for someone to explain this with example,what advantages it has in which scenarios? Does layering not localizes changes and reduces ripple effect of changes in software?

Answer (score 2):

You’ve misinterpreted the way the principle is written. The author wasn’t trying to say “avoid micro services”. They were trying to say “When dealing with a micro service, don’t keep adding features or functionality to it. Instead, add an additional micro service to deliver the new functionality.”

The intent is to help you keep each micro service focused on a single task. This simplifies any system that depends on your service. And, it means you can more easily update your service — possibly by quickly rewriting it if you come up with a better performing design, for example. It’s hard to say “we’re going to rewrite our server” if that’s a six month task. It’s much easier when it’s only a one- or two-sprint task.

Answer (score 0):

This thread needs a reboot coz of 2 reasons.

1. The Clean Code book that I have doesn't have a mention of Micro Layers. So not sure where the now "omni"-downloaded Clean Code cheat sheet got this from.

*It would help if someone can guide me to where in the Clean Code book I can read on this one.*

2. Am not fully satisfied that we re discussing Micro Layers in the scope of Micro Services. Bringing in an arch pattern Micro Services is not helping discuss a topic in a book that was written at a base level of Code and OOAD and a bit of design.

*Instead for practical illustration purpose a code level example of the above statement is needed.*

Comment: So should it be removed from the Cheat sheet? What happens next